# Change python2.7 to python3.7 for root on MAC OS

Tags: python, macos

I recently had to installed python3.7.
 I did it with homebrew under my own login name on my MAC. It has been installed under

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
```

The problem now is that root has access to the older `python2.7` but not the new `python3.7`.

under my account `which python` returns `/opt/local/bin/python`, which points towards `/opt/local/bin/python3.7`
whereas under root `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`.

I would like the root to **see** the new installation of python. How should I do this?

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978383/how-to-use-pyenv-with-another-user
I would *strongly recommend* not fiddling around with `root` user path, specially in MacOS.  Why do you need that particular user to have that particular `python` version?  Maybe there is another more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

This particular problem has nothing to do with `python`, or with `macos` in particular, instead it is a shell initialisation issue.  In particular, you are simply needed to alter the appropriate shell's profile to augment the `PATH` for `root`.

However, as has been noted in a comment, altering the environment for `root` is generally a **truly terrible idea**.  It is quite possible that there are scripts or tools run as `root` which expect the default `python` to be `2.7`.

Assuming that does not phase you and you are intent on destruction then:

- discover the default shell and home directory for `root`.  It will probably be `/bin/sh` and `/var/root` respectively.

  ```
  $ sudo su - root
  root# echo $SHELL $HOME
  /bin/sh /var/root
  ```
- `/bin/sh` is a posix compliant `sh` (implemented either by `bash`, `dash` or `zsh`).  Thus, it should suffice to edit, and add, `/var/root/.profile` to contain:

  ```
   PATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:"$PATH"
   export PATH
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I do not want to screw up my system, but I keep this in mind.